# Canvas + SurfaceView: Draw the track of touch events

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am using a combination of a SurfaceView and a Canvas so I can draw a circle with its center at the point that my finger touches the screen. 
Not only that, I want the circle to follow my finger during ACTION_MOVE events. It is successful on most of the aspects, but there is a significant lag between the touch point and the circle center, when i drag my finger very fast on the screen. The same thing happens on multitouch too (up to 10 fingers).
Is there something I can do, in order to improve this aspect, so i can actually have a circle under my finger during the whole touch?

Here is my code:

private RelativeLayout parentLayout;
    private CanvasView canvas;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

    canvas = new CanvasView(this);
    parentLayout.addView(canvas); 

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    canvas.digestMotionEvent(event);
    return true;
}



private class CanvasView extends SurfaceView {

    private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private final HashMap<Integer,Point> eventPoints;
    private final Bitmap bmp;

    public CanvasView(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.setFormat(android.graphics.PixelFormat.RGB_565);

        eventPoints = new HashMap<Integer,Point>();

        Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false; 
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red_circle, options);
    }

    public boolean digestMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
        || event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
        || event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
        || event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP
        || event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                eventPoints.put(event.getPointerId(0) , new Point(event.getX(0), event.getY(0)));
            }
            else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                eventPoints.put(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) , new Point(event.getX(event.getActionIndex()), event.getY(event.getActionIndex())));
            }
            else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
                eventPoints.remove(event.getPointerId(0));
            }
            else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
                eventPoints.remove(event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()));
            }

            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                //canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);

                /*Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
                canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC));*/

                if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    for(byte i=0;i<event.getPointerCount();i++){
                        eventPoints.get(event.getPointerId(i)).setXandY(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, event.getX(i)-15, event.getY(i)-30, null);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    for(Point p : eventPoints.values()) {
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, p.getX()-15, p.getY()-30, null);
                    }
                }

                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I have also tried the alternative of drawing a circle instead of loading a bitmap image, but the performance remained.
I have tried to remove the HashMap (it will be useful later for me) but i saw no improvement.
On the comment lines there are some other solutions i tried for reseting the canvas, but none of them was better.

My testing device is Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Subsequent calls to `lockCanvas()` / `unlockCanvasAndPost()` will be spaced at 16.67ms intervals, assuming a 60fps display refresh rate.  If your touch events are arriving more often, then your display updates will necessarily fall behind.  I think what you want to do is gather up the touch events and draw the accumulated set when the display updates.  You can use Choreographer to get a vsync callback.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I got you right, i am bounded by the hardware, and the code cannot do better, except from reducing the number of the updates I send to the Surface.
So you suggest that I "synchronize" the event processing, with my screen's fps rate, by rendering with the help of `Choreographer.postFrameCallback()`?

Comment: You can't update the display faster than the hardware refresh, which is typically 60fps.  I suspect you're getting touch events more often and are getting backed up.  One simple thing you could try is to just save the touch event in a field, rather than drawing immediately, and and then draw the most-recently-seen value 60x per second.  Using Choreographer will keep you in sync with the display.

Comment: Good.Thanks for your comments and suggestions!